# travelling to Denmark during covid

Tags: trains, germany, europe, covid-19, denmark

Can we travel to Denmark as a tourist in early April from Germany? Given that we have a residence permit for Germany. If yes, do we require corona tests?

Is there any place at all where we can travel from Germany easily during these times?

Answer (score 11):

> Can we travel to Denmark as a tourist ?

Unknown. This would be a difficult trip to do and will require a few hours of research just to find out the details for your specific situation.

Here are a few points that I have found but since rules are hard to interpret and changing very quickly these may not be up to date or accurately represented

1. Denmark only allows entry from foreign citizens for "worthy causes" which doesn't include tourism
2. Denmark requires negative Covid before arrival, mandatory testing on arrival and 10 days mandatory quarantine
3. Return into Germany depends on where exactly you stay in Denmark. Some areas in Denmark are classified as risk areas (Risikogebiete) others are not. Classification gets update about once a week.
4. Quarantine rules for return is up to the individual German states, so you need to check with the state where you reside.
5. Implementation of the quarantine rules is up to the local health offices (Gesundheitsamt) and I had two neighboring offices interpreting the same rules quite differently. Expect significant local variations.

> **Should** we travel to Denmark as a tourist

Absolutely not. Pretty much every country including Germany and Denmark strongly advise against any type of travel unless there are extremely important reasons, which tourism really isn't.  Just hang un there for a few month until the the vaccinations have reached critical level. Travel will be a lot more fun then too.

Comment: 6. Germany is seriously considering prohibiting outbound tourism completely.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any place at all where we can travel from Germany easily during these times?

You can „travel“ to:

- Google Streetview
- Google Earth
- TV travel documentaries
- Atlases
- Travel guidebooks / Wikivoyage
- Other online options