# Can I enter Denmark by car without a PCR test?

Tags: covid-19, borders, denmark

I want to travel to Denmark from the Netherlands by car. Is there any border control at the German or Danish border? Do I need a valid PCR test to enter the country?

Comment: Related, though a few months old:  [Travelling to Denmark during COVID](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/162955/travelling-to-denmark-during-covid)

Comment: Whether there is a check or not, if you are required to have a valid test, get one. It is not just for you but for the safety of all of us.

Comment: I agree with Willeke, we don't speculate in the chances of getting caught on Stack Exchange.

Comment: Totally agree. Its just not specifically mentioned for car case. But since its generalized I suppose I need test.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From https://en.coronasmitte.dk/rules-and-regulations/entry-into-denmark/categorization-of-countries

If you live in Netherlands, that is an orange country (yes I know, but now also according to the Danish classification) you need:

- Test before arriving in Denmark
- Test after arrival
- Isolation after arrival

**The tests could be PCR or quick antigen tests.**

The test after arrival is free. You can find a list of testing sites at https://en.coronasmitte.dk/rules-and-regulations/entry-into-denmark/legal-requirements-upon-entry/new-mandatory-testing-and-isolation-requirements# under the heading "Where can one be tested?"

All requirements are void if you are fully vaccinated more than two weeks ago or was previously infected.

Note that the country classifications can change every week.

Comment: This assumes that you cross Germany without intermediate stop ("usual" stops for fueling or lunch breaks are ok). Otherwise you need to "check in" at https://www.einreiseanmeldung.de/